# Cannot read property 'URL' of undefined - accessing JSON object

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic2

From the `app.component.ts` file, I am getting back data in the form of `[Object Object]` from `alert(this.datas);` but `alert(this.datas.ReportDtDataForMAPP);` gives blank result as a result of which when I try to access the report URL from the UI, I get this error : `Cannot read property 'URL' of undefined`.

Can someone please provide a solution?

Below are the necessary files:

**app.component.ts class(excerpt)**

```
//...
//Lines of code
//...

this.myMobileDataService.checkAuthorization(this.enterpriseId,v2Token)
    .subscribe(
        response => {
            this.datas = response;

            JSON.stringify(this.datas);

            alert(this.datas);

            alert(this.datas.ReportDtDataForMAPP);

            if(this.datas == null || this.datas == ""){
                this.nav.setRoot(this.accessDeniedPage, {showFooter : false});
            } else {
                this.nav.setRoot(this.homePage, {showFooter : false});
            }
        },
        err => {
            console.log("Error here!:"+err);           
        }
        );

    },


//...
//Lines of code
//...

OpenReport(report : any)
{
        let list = this.datas.ReportDtDataForMAPP;
        let newList = list.filter((t) => t.SubReport == report);
        JSON.stringify(newList)
        this.myURL = newList[0].URL;
        this.openUrl(this.myURL);

}

//...
//Lines of code
//...
```

**app.html(excerpt)**

```
 //...
 //Lines of code
 //...
 <ion-grid>

    <ion-row>
      <ion-col class="reportHeader reportHeaderPadding"><strong>AAA</strong></ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row text-center>
      <ion-col (click)="OpenReport('MURLAAA')" tappable><img src = "assets/icon/AAA.png" alt = "Image Not Available" class = "homeImages"></ion-col>
      <ion-col (click)="OpenReport('MURLBBB')" tappable> <img src = "assets/icon/BBB.png" alt = "Image Not Available" class = "homeImages"></ion-col>
       <ion-col (click)="OpenReport('MURLCCC')" tappable> <img src = "assets/icon/CCC.png" alt = "Image Not Available" class = "homeImages"></ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row text-center class="addBorder">
      <ion-col (click)="OpenReport('MURLAAA')" tappable class="reportName">AAA</ion-col>
      <ion-col (click)="OpenReport('MURLBBB')" tappable class="reportName">BBB</ion-col>
      <ion-col (click)="OpenReport('MURLCCC')" tappable class="reportName">CCC</ion-col>
    </ion-row>

    //...
    //Lines of code
    //...
```

**myMobileDataService.ts class**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Headers,RequestOptions } from  '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';


@Injectable()
export class myMobileDataService {

  constructor(private http: Http, private platform: Platform) {}

  public checkAuthorization( _enterpriseID: string, _token : any ) : Observable<any>{

    let details = {
                     "EntId" : "_enterpriseID"
                   };

    let body = JSON.stringify(details);

    let headers = new Headers(
        {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',  
          'Authorization' : 'bearer ' +  _token
        }
      );

    let options = new RequestOptions({headers:headers});

    return this.http.post('myURL',body,options)
             .map( (res) => res.json())


  }

}
```

**The http post request gives data in this form:**

```
ReportDtDataForMAPP:[
{
  "MainReport": "AAA",
  "SubReport": "aaa",
   "URL": "https://aaa@aaa.com"
},
{
  "MainReport": "BBB",
  "SubReport": "bbb",
   "URL": "https://bbb@bbb.com"
},
{
  "MainReport": "CCC",
  "SubReport": "ccc",
   "URL": "https://ccc@ccc.com"
}


 ]
```

Comment: Instead of `alert(this.datas);`, `console.log` the serialized json of `this.datas` to check if the service really returns the stuffs that you are looking for.

Comment: @SayanPal this is also printing [object Object]

Comment: That does not seem right, as `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.data))` should show the json representation of `this.data`. Are you sure you are doing that?

Comment: Nope, it's printing [object Object] only..I rechecked..where I might be possibly going wrong?

Comment: That is really strange. In that case, I am not sure what is happening here. I suggest you to debug your app in browser and check for the object. Apart from that, I really don't have any other pointers.

Comment: Is this the JSON file the real file you're trying to get from the server? It doesn't seems to be valid...
It should look like `{ "ReportDtDataForMAPP": [ ... ] }.
Although if that was the case, the app should have thrown an exception...

Comment: No @Catalyst there is nothing wrong with the JSON file

Answer (score 0):

When this function is called:

```
OpenReport(report : any)
{
        let list = this.datas.ReportDtDataForMAPP;
        let newList = list.filter((t) => t.SubReport == report);
        JSON.stringify(newList)
        this.myURL = newList[0].URL;
        this.openUrl(this.myURL);

}
```

The data is not loaded as `subscribe` is async : https://angular.io/guide/http

## More

Lookup async programming in javascript